# Select rows between two elements in a table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I have a table. I would like to select all `tr` elements between two selected elements with jQuery.

My attempt is this:

```
$('tr:has(td.selected:first)').nextUntil('tr:has(td.selected:last)').
    addClass('test');
```

But I selects the last element. Why ?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/k4fMM/

Answer (score 2):

Actually that was pretty easy: (I am still open to other ways of doing it)

```
$('tr:has(td.selected):first').nextUntil('tr:has(td.selected):last').
    addClass('test');
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V6fC3/

Answer (score 0):

The `:first` and `:last` selectors aren't working in the context that you're using them, because only one instance of `td.selected` is matched in each `has()` block, so what ends up happening is everything between the first `tr:has(.selected)` to the second `tr:has(.selected)` is matched, *but* everything after the second `tr:has(.selected)` is matched *as well*.

Your best bet to fix this may be to do something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/mC5qz/